# JSON encode data not parsing to JqPlot Chart in PhP script

Tags: javascript, php, json, jqplot

I have been searching stack overflow and other sites on this one for a few days and can't find enough information to solve my exact problem.
I have also referred to 'create web charts with JqPlot' by Fabio Nelli, while a great book it does not address my circumstances.
I do not have a great grasp of java script which may be some of my problem.
I am trying to get some data charted into a bar graph and think that the data is not getting encoded to JSON in the required format leading to the failure.
I may also not have my JavaScript component of my php document structured correctly.
(My source MySQL data is being handled by PhP and builds the required table - my theory behind this is to pull a table up and use to compare with a JqPlot Chart).

My bits of relevant code
Head:

```
<script type='text/javascript'> chart_data = ".json_encode($data_array).";</script>
```

Body (after fetching php variables as array through a html form filtering the data)

```
// creates array for json_encode
$data_array [] = array($inj_data2['count'], $damage_data2['count']);
```

Section that outputs the chart canvas and hopefully colorful data (using Bootstrap)

```
print ("<div class='panel-group'>
                    <div class='panel panel-default'>
                    <div class='col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6'><div class='row'><div id='chartdiv'></div>");
```

And for page loading speed the Jq Plot is at the foot of the script:

```
?>
</body> <!-- side bar chart source info http://www.jqplot.com/examples/barTest.php# !-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquerychart/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquerychart/jquery.jqplot.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquerychart/jqplot.barRenderer.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquerychart/jqplot.pieRenderer.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquerychart/jqplot.categoryAxisRenderer.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquerychart/jqplot.pointLabels.js"></script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquerychart/jquery.jqplot.css" />

        <script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    var plot4 = $.jqplot('chartdiv', [chart_data],  

        {
            stackSeries: true,
            captureRightClick: true,
            seriesDefaults:{
                renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer,
                shadowAngle: 135,
                rendererOptions: {
                    barDirection: 'horizontal',
                    highlightMouseDown: true   
                },
                pointLabels: {show: true, formatString: '%'}
            },
            legend: {
                show: true,
                location: 'e',
                placement: 'within'
            },
            title:"Incidents by Department",
            axes: {
                yaxis: {
                    renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
</html>
```

I have checked the json_encode array with

```
print json_encode($data_array);
```

And this is output to the browser

```
[["5","1"],["1","1"],["1","0"]]
```

These data sets are what I am after, however I believe the " " symbols are what is causing the issue?

I also wish to be able to create labels based on variables (expecting this will require JSON also) and would appreciate pointers on this.
My constraints are that I do not want any AJAX calls and wish to be able to pass all the data within the php script this is written in.

The current code returns a blank canvas below the table, and Firebug console returns:

```
Error: No data specified
```

All feedback will be greatly appreciated, please remember JavaScript is not a strong point for me.
The chart also works if data is manually input to the code (ruling out any basic issues around resources).
Cheers Jase

Comment: `<script type='text/javascript'> chart_data = ".json_encode($data_array).";</script>` - this means you're not transfering the data via an AJAX call but directly embed it in the html document. Therefore the actual data, as the javascript interpreter "sees" it, should be visible in the browser's source view. Do you see `chart_data =[["5","1"],["1","1"],["1","0"]];` there?

Comment: Hi @VolkerK thanks for your comment, apologies on the late response - when viewing the page source the header still shows the original code <script type='text/javascript'> chart_data = ".json_encode($data_array).";</script>

Comment: @VolkerK I have managed to remove the double quotes by declaring the variable type in the array <code>$data_array [] = array((int)$inj_data2['count'],(int)$damage_data2['count']);</code> this now outputs to the browser as <code>[[3,1],[1,0],[1,0]]</code>

Comment: however it looks as though I have not parsed this value through to the javascript object `chart_data` so in my very limited knowledge I believe my problem is around how i am trying to construct my javascript to contain the var in the mean time I will try and read up on javascript - I do not want to construct ajax calls all I want to be able to do is give chart_data the json_encode($my_php_array) value from the same script. This is all being tested on a local host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem (99%) I had - it may not be pretty or technically correct ..... if it can be improved upon please let me know......

Converting the variables to an array and removing the double quotes - I needed to declare each variable as the variable type within the array.
Within the php body

```
$data_array [] = array((int)$inj_data2['count'],(int)$damage_data2['count']);
```

This was the bit that stumped me for days...
Convert the php array into a JSON object using json_encode.
I knew I had to create a javascript object but a little stuck.
I was mistakenly missing out the php tags in the javascript
My fix was to place this code in the foot (after the body close tag) of he document like this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'> var chart_data = <?php echo json_encode($data_array);?></script>
```

Then declare this javascript variable within the JqPlot code like this:

```
var plot4 = $.jqplot('chartdiv', chart_data,  

        {
```

Hopefully this can assist someone in the future I still need to work out how to add the required text labels from variables.
Cheers Jase